# Problem with resuming a custom build blocking activity

Tags: elsa-workflows

I am trying to create a blocking activity. When resuming the workflow, I call workflowLaunchpad.ExecutePendingWorkflowAsyc() and this call throws a System.ObjectDisposedException exception.

the callstack of the exception:

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(System.Type)
    MediatR.ServiceFactoryExtensions.GetInstances<T>(MediatR.ServiceFactory)
    MediatR.Internal.NotificationHandlerWrapperImpl<TNotification>.Handle(MediatR.INotification, System.Threading.CancellationToken, MediatR.ServiceFactory, System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Func<MediatR.INotification, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>>, MediatR.INotification, System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)
    MediatR.Mediator.PublishNotification(MediatR.INotification, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    MediatR.Mediator.Publish<TNotification>(TNotification, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    Elsa.Services.Workflows.WorkflowRegistry.FindInternalAsync(System.Func<Elsa.Providers.Workflows.IWorkflowProvider, System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<Elsa.Services.Models.IWorkflowBlueprint>>, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]
```

I am trying to call this from a API endpoint. The code is very simple, as I am only evaluating ELSA for one of my next project.

```
    [Route("api/test")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {

        private ISharePointTaskInvoker invoker;
        private IWorkflowLaunchpad workflowLaunchpad;
        public TestController(ISharePointTaskInvoker invoker, IWorkflowLaunchpad workflowLaunchpad)
        {
            this.workflowLaunchpad = workflowLaunchpad;
            this.invoker = invoker; 
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async void Post(RequestData data)
        {           
            var q = new WorkflowsQuery(nameof(SharePointTask), new SharePointTaskBookmark(), data.CorrelationId, data.WorkflowInstanceId);

            IEnumerable<CollectedWorkflow> wfs = await workflowLaunchpad.FindWorkflowsAsync(q);
            
            foreach(CollectedWorkflow wf in wfs)
            {
                 await workflowLaunchpad.ExecutePendingWorkflowAsync(wf);
            }

        }
    }


    public class RequestData
    {
        public string WorkflowInstanceId { get; set; }
        public string ActivityId { get; set; }
        public string CorrelationId { get; set; }

    }
```

Do you have an idea, what I am missing, that's causing this ObjectDisposedException?

Comment: Hard to say (for me) without seeing the code execute with a debugger, but it could be a lifetime scope issue, where e.g. a scoped services is injected into a singleton-like service.

Comment: If you want, feel free to send me over your (stripped-down) POC that reproduces this issue so I can help figure it out.